# How to get user's profile from id?

Tags: php, facebook

Mates,
I have a database with facebook id's.
I'm tryin' to print an anchor to each's profile.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Pablo

Comment: `facebook.com/<facebookid>` would redirect you to the profile page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you really need to do is to place the users ID after Facebook's url:

```
https://facebook.com/USER_ID
```

or

```
https//facebook.com/profile.php?id=USER_ID
```

This in turn will get redirected to the users actual profile page which is more likely to appear like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME
```

---

As a side note, you can also use a similar URL to get the users profile picture:

```
<img src="https://facebook.com/USER_ID/picture">
```

Comment: Was that way. I've tried it, but didn't work with two id's.
Thanks

Comment: @pab - Perhaps those users have some other privacy settings that prevent their profile being viewed by non-friends...